# How can I create slash commands from Discord.py in a different file than the bot.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My files are structured like this:
the main.py starts the bot by executing a method to start the bot from bot.py. So far I've done it like this:

```
def run_discord_bot():
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=";", intents=discord.Intents.all())

    @bot.event
    async def on_ready():
        print(f'{bot.user} is now running.')

    #Here are other events

    #Here are the slash commands

    bot.run(TOKEN)
```

My slasch commands are just below and look like this:

```
@bot.tree.command(name="changenick", description="Ändert deinen Nickname, nachdem er von einerm Moderator überprüft wurde.")
    @app_commands.describe(nickname = "Dein neuer Nickname.")
    async def ChangeNick_SC(interaction: discord.Interaction, nickname: str):
        await Nick_Handler.ChangeNick(interaction, bot, nickname)
```

My question is how can I outsource the slash commands to one or more files?

I've really searched a lot on Google and here on stack overflow but didn't find anything really suitable and understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## What to do?

The main and easiest thing you could do in this is simply implement [cogs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=cog#discord.ext.commands.Cog), cogs can be added by running

```py
client.load_extension(name="")
```

## First

```
# cogs/special.py

import discord
from discord.ext import commands

# Class containing slash commands
class special(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @discord.app_commands.command(name="special")
    async def special_command(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message(content="Special indeed.")

# Setup method
async def setup(client: commands.Bot):
    await client.add_cog(special(client)) # This is global, add guild argument for testing.
```

> you want to create a directory where all your cogs will be stored, this is commonly put inside /cogs. and create a basic slash command cog in there. this is my example but you can change it however you want but make sure you have the setup method.

## Second

```
class Client(commands.Bot):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(command_prefix="-", intents=discord.Intents.all())

    # Method that loads cogs
    async def setup_hook(self) -> None:
        
        await self.load_extension("cogs.special") # Load cogs/special.py
        await self.tree.sync() # This is global, add guild argument for testing.
```

> you want to create a class that inherits from discord.ext.commands.Bot to provide easy modular access as well as being able to customize it however you want (in this case adding cogs)

## Third

```
# Method that starts the client
async def run():
    async with client:
        await client.start(token, reconnect=True) # Start client and allow for reconnecting

try:
    client = Client() # Create instance of client
    asyncio.run(run()) # Run main method

except Exception as error:
    print("Script Ending") # Error handling
    raise(error)
```

> Just start it up, I used asyncio to start my script for my example but you can use any method you like.

## Here's main.py for you:

```
# main.py

import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

token = "" # Token Here

# Inherit from commands.Bot to create your own client
class Client(commands.Bot):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(command_prefix="-", intents=discord.Intents.all())

    # Method that loads cogs
    async def setup_hook(self) -> None:
        
        await self.load_extension("cogs.special") # Load cogs/special.py
        await self.tree.sync() # This is global, add guild argument for testing.

# Method that starts the client
async def run():
    async with client:
        await client.start(token, reconnect=True) # Start client and allow for reconnecting

try:
    client = Client() # Create instance of client
    asyncio.run(run()) # Run main method

except Exception as error:
    print("Script Ending") # Error handling
    raise(error)
```

I encourage you use the [discord.py documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) in your journey since it can be really helpful, if you have any questions im happy to answer them.

## Long game

```
class Cogs:
    """
    Class which holds methods that have to do with locating and using cog files.
    """
    @classmethod
    def FindAll(cls, directory: str, extension: str = ".py", exclusions: Union[List[str], str] = ["__init__.py"]) -> list:
        """
        Finds all cogs within a certain directory, excluding everything that matches exclusions

        Arguments
        ~~~~~~~~~

        `REQUIRED` directory: str
            Location to look for cog files

        `OPTIONAL` extension: str
            Ending of a file to be considered a cog
            (defaults to `.py`)

        `OPTIONAL` exclusions: Union[List[str], str]
            exlusions that will be ignored as cog files
            (defaults to ["__init__.py"])
           
        """

        # Convert Exclusions to a list if its a string.
        if isinstance(exclusions, str):
            exclusions = [exclusions]

        cog_locations = []
        for root, _, files in os.walk(directory):
            for file in files:
                file: str

                if not isinstance(file, str):
                    continue

                if not file.endswith(extension) or file in exclusions:
                    continue

                cog_locations.append(os.path.relpath(os.path.join(root, file), os.getcwd()).replace("\\", ".").replace(extension, "").replace("/", "."))

        return cog_locations
```

> Since individually adding cogs if you have 10s if not 100s of cogs can be quite annoying having to add every single cog with self.load_extension, you should implement some sort of function that automatically finds every cog inside a directory, here's my solution (that im sure can be simplified) but for now you don't need it.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer! Yes, I also searched the doc, but it was difficult for me to find anything there. I'll change my code accordingly, but I still have two questions: Do I understand correctly that the difference between client.run() and client.start() is that you can add slash commands to client.start() after the fact? and not with client.run()?
And how can I add descriptions to the parameters of a slash command? Previously it was easy with @discord.app_commands.description() but now there is an error

Comment: @MAB Apologies for the late reply, The only difference between [client.run()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=client%20run#discord.Client.run) and [client.start()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=client%20start#discord.Client.start) is that client.run() has more parameters compared to client.start(). As to how you can add descriptions to your slash commands all you need to do is add a description parameter to discord.app_commands.command(), making it discord.app_commands.command(name="command_name", description="description")